# Get-SPUser and a Person field

Tags: powershell

What is the correct powershell syntax for finding all list items in a given list where a Person field matches a user retrieved from Get-SPUser?

I.e.

```
$user = Get-SPUser -web *web* -Identity *domain\user*

$listItems = $web.Lists["*listName*"].Items | Where-Object $_.["*personField*"] -eq $user
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's something I wrote for another project:

```
Function Convert-SPFieldUserValueToSPUser {
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ValueFromPipeline=$true,ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
        [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItem] $item,
        [Alias("field","name")]
        [string] $fieldName
    )

    ($item.Fields[$fieldName]).GetFieldValue($item[$fieldName]).User | Write-Output
}
```

Then, you can use this function as follows:

```
$userLogin = '*domain\user*';
$listItems = $web.Lists["*listName*"].Items | `
    Where-Object (($_ | Convert-SPFieldUserValueToSPUser -field "*personField*").LoginName -eq $userLogin);
```